# Scheduled alarm not fired

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am scheduling events. Based on event type it is scheduled for specific days(example only Friday and Sunday) or all the days of a week.

**Problem** 
The notification that I have created is not getting fired.I have searched in Google but couldn't find what is causing error. 
My code is below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("HABIT_NAME", habitName.getText().toString());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), eventId, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    if(daysNo.size() == 7){ //set for whole week
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                reminderLifeTS.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60*24*7, pendingIntent); 
    }
   else{ //set for specific days
        for(int i=0;i<daysNo.size();i++){
            int day = getWeek(daysNo.get(i));
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, reminderLifeTS.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, reminderLifeTS.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            System.out.println("day of week is : " + day);
            System.out.println("reminderLifeTS.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) is : " + reminderLifeTS.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            System.out.println("reminderLifeTS.get(Calendar.MINUTE) is : " + reminderLifeTS.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    c.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60*24, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

**BroadCastReceiver:**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
   Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
   String habitName = intent.getStringExtra("HABIT_NAME");
   service1.putExtra("HABIT_NAME", habitName);
   context.startService(service1);

}
```

**MyAlarmService**

```
       @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
   {
       super.onStart(intent, startId);
       String habitName = intent.getStringExtra("HABIT_NAME");

       mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().
               getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

       intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

       PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
               this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

       // megha
       NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
               new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
               .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
               .setContentTitle("DharmaLife")
               .setContentText(habitName)
               .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
               .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);

       Notification note = mBuilder.build();
       note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
       note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
       note.flags|= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

       PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
       WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK |
               PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
       wakeLock.acquire();
       // end megha


       mManager.notify(0, note);
    }
```

**Edit**
**for all the days is working fine:**

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    reminderLifeTS.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Can anyone guide me for specific days.

**for specific days:**

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    c.getTimeInMillis(),7*24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

is working for me.

Comment: have You just checked the date given by Calendar if it is really is in future?

Comment: Hi Megha,Have you Register the receiver in the manifest?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs its correct time.

Comment: Have you tried using START_STICKY?? Also please debug your code and check where it trips? At what point?

Comment: also registered the service in manifest? And in which clock mode You are using 12 hour with am/pm or 24 hour?

Comment: i think you are missing something. Time is not going right. Add calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); after
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); See this link. https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html This link will help you.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs service is registered. time is in 24 hours format

Comment: Is there any limit to number of notification that can be registered from one App?

Comment: Are You using API <5 ? Because I would recommend that You use onStartCommand() instead of onStart(), You should first return START_STICKY and of course stopSelf();

Comment: You might wanna check if your not using one of Chinese phones, those are killing apps and scheduled tasks like a flies. For example Oppo phone.